# If stock like GOOG does not pay dividends, what is the use of holding onto it?

Tags: stocks

I don't own many GOOG shares, but those that I do own have increased in value. It seems, though, that growth has flattened and the value is only fluctuating within a fairly stable range.

Why should I hold onto it if I'm not going to get any dividends from it?